# What is the exact function of たる?

Tags: adjectives, sentence

恐怖が屈辱たる世界で

あの家系に恐怖する人のなんと多いことか

My understand of the sentence is this in word fear is a disgrace and then he points out many people fear that household

Hover I don't understand  how たる is being used here?

Comment: One of these should answer your question: [use of たる in 礎たる資質](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19442/45489) / [How interchangeable are の／である／なる／たる when qualifying nouns?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13697/45489) / [What's the literal and natural translation of たるもの?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2191/45489)