# What's the difference between 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 ?

Tags: grammar, syntax

I am beginner to Japanese language. I am using Genki as textbook. I came across this sentence in one of the exercises:

> あなたの学校に日本人の学生がいますか。

Why is it **日本人**の**学生** here and not **日本**の**学生** ? 
Wouldn't 日本の学生 (Student of Japan/ Japanese student) make more sense than 日本人の学生 (Japanese person student) ?

Am I interpreting it wrong ?

Comment: 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 are the same in meaning and both common. What's the difference between "Student of Japan" and "Japanese student"?

Comment: @YuuichiTam If `AのB` could always be translated as `B of A` mechanically, then 日本人の学生 should mean "student of Japanese people", which makes little sense to me.

Comment: See also [How interchangeable are の／である／なる／たる when qualifying nouns?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13697/78).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`A の B` has many meanings, depending on the relationship of `A` and `B`:

1. (possession/affiliation/belonging) `B of A`, `A's B`, `B which belongs to A`

   - 彼の友達 his friend, a friend of his
   - 私の車 my car
   - 日本の都市 Japanese cities
2. (state/description/apposition) `B that is A`, `B, being A` (in this case, の is interchangeable with である)

   - 友達のマイケル my friend Micheal
   - トナカイのルドルフ Rudolph the reindeer
   - 医者の乗客 a passenger who is a doctor
3. [... and many others](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/171157/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AE/)

Occasionally it can be hard to tell between 1. and 2. For example, 犯罪者の子供 may mean either "the criminal's child" (the child himself is not a criminal) or "a child who is a criminal", depending on the context.

In your case, the first definition is applied for 日本の学生 ("a student of Japan"), and the second definition is applied for 日本人の学生 ("a student who is a Japanese person"). They both mean the same thing, *Japanese student(s)*.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 was maybe unnatural to say. So, it's basically interchangeable! I didn't know you could use の particle like you described in [2]. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @retrazil FWIW, English 'of' has many meanings. "The city of London" refers to London City itself, not a city that belongs to London.