# What does 「アニメ」 mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, words, sentence

I know 「アニメ」 as short for 「アニメーション」, meaning an animated film/cartoon; I tried on Jisho and Weblio, but I couldn't find any other meaning.

Yet I found these senteces, which I'm not sure about by reading 「アニメ」 with that meaning:

First (and less problematic) one; context: three middle school students are using the school ground to practice baseball, and one of them says he is going home earlier than expected:

> 日はまだ中天{ちゅうてん}にある。影浩{あきひろ}はわずかに目を細めてみた。
>
> 「どうした？何かあったんか？」
>
> 「別に。三年やし、ちっとは勉強しよかて思うてな」
>
> 「は？ふざけんなや。おまえが勉強するなら、**うちのアニメだって問題集を広げてるぞ**」

Is this something like "Eh? If even you study, we should add anime to the exercise collection" (lit.: we should expand the exercise collection with anime)? If so, why 「うちのアニメ」 instead of just 「アニメ」?

Second (and more problematic) one; context: Akihiro is home, his father is watching television; sometimes news about Koushien appears, and Akihiro is pissed off by this:

> 同じ国に生まれ、同じ年齢でありながら、自分と彼らの間には無限にも思える隔たりがある。
>
> 「ほんま、格差社会やな」
>
> ほろりと言葉が零れた。父がテレビの前か振り返り、なんだ？と問う代わりに、瞬きをする。画面が変わり、女子ゴルファーの頭が大きく映し出されたのを潮に影浩は腰を上げた。**老猫{ろうびょう}のアニメ**が遠慮のない欠伸を漏らす

Does this mean something like, "He didn't hold back and yawned, like a cartoon old cat"? If so, I'm not sure about the sentence structure, since by reading it I'd say it means "The old anime cat yawned without holding back", but even so I'm not sure about why 「老猫のアニメ」 (which sounds to me like "The anime of the old cat") instead of 「アニメの老猫」.

With that translation it could make sense if it were speaking about an anime on television, but since there were Koushien news and a female golfer appeared, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, this アニメ is the name of an old cat. うちの clearly indicates this アニメ belongs to the speaker's home or family. The の in 老猫のアニメ is an apposition marker (i.e., アニメ is an 老猫). See: [What's the difference between 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40892/5010)

Comment: What does 「おまえが勉強するなら、うちのアニメだって問題集を広げてるぞ」 means? Seems like "If you study, also our cat", then something about opening/spreading a collection of problems, but I don't understand it.

Comment: @Maruo It's a joke that roughly means "If you say you are studying, I will say my cat is studying (bacause your statement is equally unbelievable as mine)."