# Adjectival noun in this sentence

Tags: sentence, relational-nouns

前日のキャンセルですと、50％のキャンセル料金をいただくことになります。

My understand for this sentence is

"If you cancel the day before, we will get 50% of the cancelling fee" (there's a fixed cancelling fee)

PS. In case my English sentence above is not understandable -> If you cancel the day before, you will have to pay 50% of the canceling fee (for example, a fixed cancelling fee is 100 USD. You cancelled the order so you have to pay 50% of the cancelling fee which is 50 USD )

Please correct me

Comment: I'm confused by your question title -- there is no "adjectival noun", as I understand that term (alternative name for "な adjective" in certain teaching materials).  Do you mean the 「50%の」 part?

Comment: I mean キャンセル料金 part. I’m not sure but I think キャンセル here is adjectival noun modifying 料金。

Comment: Ah, no, that's not an adjectival noun -- that's just a noun used attributively in what's sometimes called a "noun stack", a bunch of nouns stuck together.  Consider the English "bathroom break allowance time", or "peanut butter sandwich".  The キャンセル here is much like the nouns in the English phrases -- just a noun, but used in a stack in an attributive way to modify a following noun.  キャンセル is "cancel", as a verb (with する), but it's also the noun "cancelling" or "cancellation".  I'd probably render キャンセル料金 as "cancellation fee", FWIW.

Comment: But anyway, my current understanding for this sentence is “If you cancel the day before, we will charge you 50% of cancelled fee (the fee that you cancelled) i.e if cancelled fee is 100USD, you have to pay 50USD for that.

Comment: Ah, ya.  Your wording is a bit odd and that confused me in your comments under Naruto's answer.  But yes, ultimately I think you're correct.  You've got a reservation for, say, ¥100,000.  If you do nothing, you pay ¥100,000.  If you cancel earlier than one day before, you pay nothing.  If you cancel one day before, you pay 50% of the ¥100,000 -- i.e. you pay ¥50,000.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for my bad English too. I’d like to mark this as the answer to my question but it’s just a comment. Naruto’s answer is wonderful too. To anyone who come and see this question, I’d like to tell you that the comment above is the best answer to my question. Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: Cheers, glad it was helpful!  I think my comment above does not go beyond just a restating of Naruto's answer; I think Naruto and I are saying the same thing in different words.  I suspect all three of us now agree on the meaning of the Japanese, and the problem now might actually be the English wording instead.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the word order carefully.

- 50％のキャンセル料金 = "[a / the] 50% cancellation fee" or "cancellation fee of 50%" (i.e., 50% of the full fee you'd be charged if you didn't cancel)
- キャンセル料金の50% = "50% of the cancellation fee" (i.e., half of the fixed cancellation fee; indeed, this doesn't make much sense in practice)

The former (which is what the sentence uses) means, for example, that if you booked a hotel for 10,000 yen and cancelled it the day before, you'd have to pay 5,000 yen as the cancellation fee.

See also: [What's the difference between 日本人の学生 and 日本の学生 ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40892/5010)

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still don't understand something. The first thing is that I'm confused a bit about "50％のキャンセル料金 = 50% cancellation fee (i.e., 50% of the fee you'd be charged if you didn't cancel)" you mentioned. I didn't mean to offense but I'm just thinking that there's a mistype -> from(i.e., 50% of the fee you'd be charged if you **didn't** cancel) to ->> (i.e., 50% of the fee you'd be charged if you **cancelled**) The reason I think so because I think when someone does not cancel (the order or something), he/she doesn't get charged.

Comment: If my opinion is correct (i.e., 50% of the fee you'd be charged if you **cancelled**)

Comment: I'd like to ask the next thing I'm not sure.
2nd thing is that after I digested your [link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40892/whats-the-difference-between-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e5%ad%a6%e7%94%9f-and-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e3%81%ae%e5%ad%a6%e7%94%9f),
I'd like to apply this 50％のキャンセル料金 to ur 2nd meaning (state/description/apposition).
Let me consider this "fee" to be "a 100USD-priced phone"
I'll retranslate again

Comment: 前日のキャンセルですと、50％のキャンセル料金をいただくことになります。 -> 
If you ordered a 100USD-priced phone (料金 that I consider to be a "100USD-phone)and you cancelled the order the next day, you will have to pay 50% of 100USD-priced phone (50% of the fee you'd be charged if you cancelled) i.e you have to pay 50USD.

Comment: Is it correct ?  Anyway,Thank you !

Comment: @Kyuu Looks like "50% of the fee you'd be charged if you didn't cancel" was ambiguous, but Eiríkr Útlendi explained it well. I meant "50% of the original/full fee".