# 日本人の男の人 vs 日本の男の人 vs <something else entirely>?

Tags: word-choice, usage, particle-の

I want to say "a Japanese man." I am still learning introductory-level Japanese, but I know I can say
男の人 to refer to a man somewhat politely. I figured I could just say 日本の男の人 to specify that the man is Japanese. Using 日本人 seems repetitive. Is this correct? If not, is it the other idea I put in the title, or is it something else entirely, such as 男の日本人?

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40892

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks! So to clarify, either way is acceptable?

Comment: Yes, 日本人の男の人 and 日本の男の人 are interchangeable in most cases. 日本人の男の人 is more explicit about nationality, and thus may be preferred when you refer to Japanese men living outside Japan.