# How do you join たる-adjectives?

Tags: grammar, て-form, adjectives, classical-japanese, conjunctions

When joining い-adjectives and な-adjectives, you simply put them in 連用形 + て:

> この料理は美味し**くて**安いです。

> 田中さんは綺麗**で**親切です。

However, I have a bit of trouble with たる-adjectives. I couldn't find any resources on it.

If I wanted to say something was 堂々たり and 平然たり, would I:

Use って 音便 as would be expected out of a ラ変:

> 堂々**たって**平然たり

Or would I ignore 音便 and stick with pure unchanged 連用形 + て because たり is a Classical Japanese auxiliary:

> 堂々**たりて**平然たり

I couldn't find any resources on the web at all on this, so I'm stumped right now. My IME seems to like たりて, whilst if I write たって it tries to auto 変換 to something like 立って・経って・建って.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Related:  [How interchangeable are の／である／なる／たる when qualifying nouns?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13697/78).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Overview: Modern Japanese

There is some brief discussion of these in the English Wikipedia, in the "*taru* adjectives" section of the "Adjectival noun" article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectival_noun_(Japanese)#taru_adjectives), and a bit more detail in the "*taru* adjectives" section of the "Japanese equivalents of adjectives" article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_equivalents_of_adjectives#taru-adjectives).

Long story short, the *-taru* adjectives in modern Japanese are basically [fossils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_word), leftovers that have eroded grammatically.  These can *only* be used in two ways:

1. to modify a noun or noun phrase, using the ～たる ending: **[堂々]{どうどう}**[た]{●}[る]{●}[物]{もの} ("a **grand** thing")
2. to modify a verb or verb phrase, using the ～と ending: **[堂々]{どうどう}**[と]{●}[行]{い}く ("to go **regally**")

You can't use them to end a sentence, and there isn't any ～て form.  In Japanese, these are often called タルト[形容]{けいよう}[動詞]{どうし}, because they only have the conjugational endings ～たる and ～と.

#### A workaround

A common modern construction that would allow you to string together ～たる adjectives with others, and not fall too far afoul of the grammarians in your audience, would be to use ～として.  ～とする is a common way to turn something into an adjectival or adverbial phrase.  It's a bit like the English construction, "it goes ～", or "it's like ～".  [女王]{じょおう}は**[堂々]{どうどう}**[と]{●}[し]{●}[て]{●}[礼儀]{れいぎ}[正]{ただ}しい[人物]{じんぶつ}です。 ("The queen is a **majestic** and courteous person.")

#### Irregularities: a language in flux

That said, poking around online does reveal that some writers in Japanese are reinterpreting the grammar: for [堂々]{どうどう} at least, I do see cases of [[堂々]{どうどう}で](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%A0%82%E3%80%85%E3%81%A7%22) and [[堂々]{どうどう}だ](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%A0%82%E3%80%85%E3%81%A0%22), which are technically incorrect according to strict style guides.  This word, and possibly this whole ～たる class of words, appears to be in flux with regard to how modern writers are handling the grammar.  I would recommend avoiding the ～で or ～だ constructions for the time being.

### Overview: Classical Japanese

If you're writing Classical Japanese, things like ～たりて are valid.  The MS IME does include some features to support Classical Japanese, since this is still used by modern writers -- particularly for high-register, formal writing.

The ～たる ending is a contraction of adverbial と + the copula ("to be" verb) ある.  Technically, the terminal (sentence-ending) and dictionary form in Classical Japanese was あり, and these adjectives could end a sentence with the ～たり ending.  So the ～たる ending conjugates just like the Classical copula あり.

Here's the conjugation chart from [the relevant Japanese Wikipedia section](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E#%E3%80%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A%E3%80%8D%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8):

未然形　    たら　　　　(*mizenkei*, or "negative stem" used with ～ない)
連用形　    たり、と　　(*ren'yōkei*, or "*-masu* stem" or "adverbial")
終止形　    たり　　　　(*shūshikei*, or "dictionary form" used to end clauses)
連体形　    たる　　　　(*rentaikei*, or "attributive form" used to modify nouns)
已然形　    たれ　　　　(*izenkei*, or "hypothetical stem" used with ～ば)
命令形　    たれ　　　　(*meireikei*, or "command form")

The ～て form used to join adjectives is from the [連用形]{れんようけい} or adverbial form, so たり + て → たりて.  Or analyzed a different way, we use the ～と adverbial form of the adjective and add on the ～て form of あり: と + ありて → たりて.

Comment: For some reason the 「**」 aren't doing their job (though when I try to edit your post, they work as intended in the preview...).

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer! I couldn't find any resources anywhere talking about this, you saved me ^_^

Comment: @Garbaz, doh!  They do indeed look correct in the preview, but not above.  How frustrating.  The markdown used on SE is poorly designed and assumes whitespace, which Japanese doesn't use.  I inserted &#x200b; entities -- zero-width spaces -- to force the issue, but it looks like these aren't rendered properly in the "regular" view, only during editing preview.  I'll have to see if anything else works correctly.

Comment: `堂々として礼儀正しい` <- 「堂々」と「平然」をつなげるには、「堂々として平然としている」？

Comment: @Chocolate, そうですね、このような文法が使われている例はまれですが存在します。例えば： https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%A0%82%E3%80%85%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E5%B9%B3%E7%84%B6%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%22

Answer (score 7):

One simple approach is to use [かつ](https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/19729/katsu), which is one of the stiffest words to say "and" in Japanese. It can be used also with i-adjectives and na-adjectives (see the link), but since most taru-adjectives are stiff and solemn, かつ works very well with them, too. Simply join the kanji parts and treat them as a long taru-adjective:

> 堂々かつ平然たる態度

Comment: Interesting! Now, かつ has a practical use. :)

Comment: And, かつ is also delicious! Yum!